# FlatList implementation in React Native - renderItem functionality unclear? - undefined property

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I'm trying to implement a flatlist which displays images from an array (which I have pulled from my firebase RTDB, but that doesn't matter). The code where I implement the FlatList is here:

```
<FlatList
    data = {poi_obj.images}
    renderItem = {({ image }) => (<Image source = {{uri: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${image.data}`}} style = {{flex: 1}} />)}
    horizontal = {true}
    initialNumToRender = {1}
/>
```

and the array of images (`poi_obj.images`) I have formatted like so:

```
[
{data: 'base64-string-blah-blah', type: 'image'}
{data: 'another-b64-string-woohoo', type: 'image'}
]
```

I am 100% positive that this is how it is formatted, as I've logged it to console just before attempting the FlatList definition. The type property is so that I can add video support later, but that isn't important now.

I am getting an error indicating that `image.data` is undefined. There is temporarily only one image in the array for testing purposes.

**My understanding:** The documentation is a bit unclear, but it seems that, while iterating through the list of images, it will perform the function defined under `renderItem` using each item of the array (filling the `{ image }` parameter in my case). There is mention of a key property, but it seems as though this is optional, and that if omitted, the library will default to the use of indices (essentially iterating through the array in order from index 0 to the end, and rendering each item). I've tried multiple methods of implementing key properties, and yet I cannot find a solution that results in a defined "data" property.

Perhaps someone with a better understanding of FlatLists in react native/expo can help me here? I've taken a look at just about every relevant thread on StackOverflow, and the documentation is somewhat unclear about the use of a key property as it pertains to array iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The argument that gets passed to the `renderItem` handler consists of an object, and the actual item (your image object, in this case) is found on the `item` property of that object. Just change the destructured parameter to the following, and it should work:

```
renderItem = {({ item }) => ...
```

Do note that it's generally recommended for performance purposes to move this prop into a function on the component rather than passing an inline function.